# Limiting pq connections SetMaxOpenConns

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using the `pq` driver (http://github.com/lib/pq) in go for writing into a postgres database, but when a lot of transactions happen at once, the driver panics and does the following:

```
pq: sorry, too many clients already
```

To prevent this behavior I wanted to use `SetMaxOpenConns` (as documented in http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/), but the compiler says:

```
db.SetMaxOpenConns undefined (type *sql.DB has no field or method SetMaxOpenConns)
```

I thought the functions from `sql` would also be available in `pq`, but apparently they aren't.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func Main() {
    var db, _ = sql.Open("postgres", "user=user dbname=db")
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(10)
}
```

Is there any other possibility to limit the amount of open connections?

Comment: The docs you pointed at are for Go 1.2.  That method doesn't seem to be in 1.1, so perhaps that is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/james-henstridge) pointed out, I referred to a function that is only available on Go 1.2, while I had still installed 1.1.

In short the Solution is: **Update to Go 1.2**